# Installing rmr2 in RHadoop

Tags: rhadoop

Can you please help me in fixing an Issue of Installing rmr2. I am new in RHadoop. 
R version 3.0.2
downloaded rmr2_2.3.0.tar.gz on root

Please check :

> install.packages("rmr2_2.3.0.tar.gz")
>   Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>   inferring 'repos = NULL' from the file name
>   ERROR: dependency ‘bitops’ is not available for package ‘rmr2’
>   * removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/rmr2’
>   Warning message:
>   In install.packages("rmr2_2.3.0.tar.gz") :
>     installation of package ‘rmr2_2.3.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

Please reply

Answer (score 2):

The rmr2 package depends upon a few other packages that you need to install before installing rmr2. To install those packages:

```
install.packages(c("rJava", "Rcpp", "RJSONIO", "bitops", "digest", "functional", "stringr", "plyr", "reshape2", "caTools"))
```

You can also run the above command from the command line with `Rscript -e 'install.packages(...)'`.

According to the [Rhadoop wiki](https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/RHadoop/wiki/rmr) they've tested this package with R 2.14.1. I've tested it with 2.15.3 without any problems. Either way, some of the dependencies may not support (in their latest version) those R versions, so you will have to download an earlier version manually.

If you're using R 2.15 you only need to download and install manually the Rcpp package, version [0.10.5](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/Rcpp/Rcpp_0.10.5.tar.gz).

Before installing rmr2 you need to make sure you have an installation of Hadoop and the proper environmental variables are set:

```
export HADOOP_CMD=/usr/bin/hadoop
export HADOOP_STREAMING=/usr/lib/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-<version>.jar
```

Now you can install the rmr2 package:

```
R CMD INSTALL rmr2_2.3.0.tar.gz
```

Comment: Will rmr2 this support yarn ?

Answer (score 1):

first download rmr2_3.0.0.tar.gz from gitHub and then from your r terminal install.packages("/home/purva/Downloads/rmr2_3.0.0.tar.gz")
at the place of purva you can write your user name.